# Read zipped files into dataframe one at a time

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, zip, boto3

I have a zip(.zip extension) in S3 which contains multiple source (csv) files. I need to read these files one by one into a dataframe, do some changes and write back to S3 as each file . My question is related to reading these source files one by one into dataframe.

I tried many solutions posted online ( including below) but it does not work. Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

```
zipped_keys =  s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter = "/")
file_list = []
for key in zipped_keys['Contents']:
    file_list.append(key['Key'])

zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=bucket, key=file_list[0])
print(zip_obj)
buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())

z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
for filename in z.namelist():
    print(filename)
    file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
    s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
        z.open(filename),
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key='target/' + f'{filename}')
```

Error: AttributeError: '_SharedFile' object has no attribute 'writing'

Comment: That code will not generate that error message.  What line, specifically, is throwing the error message?

Comment: @AnonCoward Error is on this line ->
    s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(